# Hibernate one-to-many save error

Tags: hibernate

I have table A and B.

B is parent of A. (B has One-to-Many with A)

I am saving data in B and A as,

```
B.add(A's List);

session.save(B);  //save Parent
```

I am able to save only 1 record.

When I again refresh same browser, its giving error as:

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: unique constraint.
```

Can anybody tell what I might missing ? Thanks.

Comment: apparently you are inserting another tuple with the same content that conflicts one existing value.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that

1. You're inserting a B in the database using a HTTP GET (which is wrong: GET is supposed to be idempotent. You should use POST)
2. You're assigning the ID of B explicitely, and since you're refreshing the page, you're inserting the same B, with the same ID, a second time.

Use the [post-redirect-get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern. (and include the stack trace of the exception, the code causing this exception and other relevant code, if my guesses are wrong and you need more help)